# Excel Formulas in Python using openpyxl library

Tags: python-3.x, excel, excel-formula, openpyxl

I am working on a report to find the peak sales hour for all the listed cities in the format as the sample screenshot attached (The left table is the raw data and the right table is the final summary report out of the left table). After I have found the peak hour using the MAX formula, I need to write the peak hour somewhere in the sheet, please note that the Total sales for a city is written in the first row of each city's data in bold text and I am searching for all the bold texts and applying the formula.

Then I need to find the average and max sales during the peak hour. In the example, for the Delhi city, the peak hour is 1am-2am, the average sale during peak hour is 73, the max sales is 89, average sales per store per hour is 60. I am doing all these using openpyxl library in Python, after studying Python openpyxl library for a few hours, below is the code I have  written so far:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import Font, Color

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:/Python-Excel/Reports.xlsx")
ws = wb['PeakHour']

for i in range(2,13):
    if ws.cell(row=i, column=2).font.b:
        ws["F" + str(i)] = '=MAX(B%s:E%s)' % (i,i)       
wb.save("C:/Python-Excel/Reports.xlsx")
```

This code is writing the max value in the F column, however, I need to write the peak hour for a city and do the further calculations as explained above. How can I achieve this[image].

Comment: Are you asking for the Excel formulae?